# How to merge files within a sub-directory and perform this function on mutliple sub-directories

Tags: python, bash, unix, concatenation

I have a directory with ~2000 sub-directories and within each sub-directory there are between 2-10 txt files. I would like to open each sub-directory and merge or concatenate the contents into a single file, thus I would have 2000 directories, each with 1 txt file. 
I have tried to do this using unix commands, but I can't seem to get the command to execute in a specific sub-directory and then change directories and perform the function again.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.faa" -exec cat {}
```

Is there a way to turn this into a bash script and have it run over the entire directory, or should I look to something more like python to try and accomplish this task.

Thank you and I apologize if this has been asked.

Comment: For the 2-10 txt files in each subdirectory, do you want them concatenated in a specific order?

Comment: no order does not matter to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you want, and can be customized to your needs:

```
import os

OLD_BASE = '/tmp/so/merge/old'
NEW_BASE = '/tmp/so/merge/new'
NEW_NAME = 'merged.txt'

def merge_files(infiles, outfile):
    with open(outfile, 'wb') as fo:
        for infile in infiles:
            with open(infile, 'rb') as fi:
                fo.write(fi.read())


for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(OLD_BASE):
    base, tail = os.path.split(dirpath)
    if base != OLD_BASE: continue  # Don't operate on OLD_BASE, only children directories

    # Build infiles list
    infiles = sorted([os.path.join(dirpath, filename) for filename in filenames])

    # Create output directory
    new_dir =  os.path.join(NEW_BASE, tail)
    os.mkdir(new_dir)  # This will raise an OSError if the directory already exists

    # Build outfile name
    outfile = os.path.join(new_dir, NEW_NAME)

    # Merge
    merge_files(infiles, outfile)
```

The end result is, for each directory in `OLD_BASE`, a directory of the same name is created in `NEW_BASE`.  Inside each `NEW_BASE` subdirectory, a file called `merged.txt` is created with the concatenated contents of the files inside the corresponding `OLD_BASE` subdirectory.

So

```
<OLD_BASE>
    DIR_1
        FILE_1
        FILE_2
    DIR_2
        FILE_3
        FILE_4
        FILE_5
    DIR_3
        FILE_6
```

Becomes

```
<NEW_BASE>
    DIR_1
        <NEW_NAME> (=FILE_1 + FILE_2)
    DIR_2
        <NEW_NAME> (=FILE_3 + FILE_4 + FILE_5)
    DIR_3
        <NEW_NAME> (=FILE_6)
```

I know you said it doesn't matter what order the files are merged, but this merges them alphabetically by filename (case-sensitive), in case future viewers are interested.  If you're really not, you can remove the `sorted()` wrapping function.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this will do:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "$0" && cat *.faa > bigfile' {} \;
```

It finds all the subdirectories (non-recursively) in current directory, `cd` into them, and concatenate all the `*.faa` files into a file called `bigfile` (inside the subdirectory).